# Define maximum RelativeLayout size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have to define 5 layouts on the screen and place them like a 3x3 grid. Layouts is empty.
[image]

At some moment I want programmatically to add some view on one layout and that view mustn't grows over allocated size of layout. In other words I want to have layout in which to put any view and it will be guaranty that it won't grows over that layout. Important note: I don't have rights to change manually size of added view, I only can to control its maximum size.

I have right now such layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/pluginsLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
    android:layout_above="@+id/mainButtons"
    android:layout_below="@+id/paramsLayout">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/capturingPluginLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"           
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|left"
            android:layout_above="@+id/processingPluginLayout">                                         
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/processingPluginLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"               
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|left"
            android:layout_above="@+id/filterPluginLayout">                                     
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/filterPluginLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|left|bottom"                
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">                                  
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/exportPluginLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"               
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|right"
            android:layout_above="@+id/viewfinderPluginLayout">                                     
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewfinderPluginLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"                                       
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|bottom|right"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/filterPluginLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">                                     
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And I added new view in code:

```
public void addVFPluginView(View view)
{       
    ((RelativeLayout)MainScreen.thiz.findViewById(R.id.viewfinderPluginLayout)).addView(view);      
}
```

I expect to got like this behaviour:

[image]

But I got only this, view fill entire parent layout:

[image]

Note: I use API8 (don't have GridLayout)

Answer (score 0):

u can use grid layout in API8.

Comment: oh..u'r right...why I had in memory other stuff? ) Will try grid!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this issue.
The main idea was to control view's sizes by myself programmatically.
I calculate appropriate proportion for each zone and when somebody add a new view to some of this layout I check suitability of the size of this view to the allocated size of layout. If size is not suitable I modify LayoutParams for this View.
Here is the xml of empty layouts:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/pluginsLayout"             
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"             
    android:layout_above="@+id/mainButtons"
    android:layout_below="@+id/paramsLayout">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/capturePluginLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">               
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/processingPluginLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">                                           
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/filterPluginLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">                                            
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/exportPluginLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"              
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">                                               
        </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewfinderPluginLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"             
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                        
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">                                                        
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And like that I manage the size of adding views:

```
public void addVFPluginView(View view)
{
    //Get maximum width and height for such plugins
    int layoutHeight = this.getViewfinderLayoutHeight();
    int layoutWidth = this.getViewfinderLayoutWidth();

    //Calculate appropriate size of added plugin's view
    android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams viewLayoutParams = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
    viewLayoutParams = this.getTunedRelativeLayoutParams(view, viewLayoutParams, layoutWidth, layoutHeight);

//Get fixed maximum size for this plugin type
public int getViewfinderLayoutWidth()
{
    return ((RelativeLayout)MainScreen.thiz.findViewById(R.id.pluginsLayout)).getWidth()/2;
}

public int getViewfinderLayoutHeight()
{
    return (int)(((RelativeLayout)MainScreen.thiz.findViewById(R.id.pluginsLayout)).getHeight()*0.7);
}


    ((RelativeLayout)MainScreen.thiz.findViewById(R.id.viewfinderPluginLayout)).addView(view, viewLayoutParams);        
}

android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams getTunedRelativeLayoutParams(View view, android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams currParams, int goodWidth, int goodHeight)
{
    int viewHeight, viewWidth;

    if(currParams != null)
    {
        viewHeight = currParams.height;
        viewWidth = currParams.width;


        if(viewHeight > goodHeight || viewHeight <= 0)
            viewHeight = goodHeight;

        if(viewWidth > goodWidth || viewWidth <= 0)
            viewWidth = goodWidth;

        currParams.width = viewWidth;
        currParams.height = viewHeight;

        view.setLayoutParams(currParams);
    }
    else
    {       
        currParams = new android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(goodWidth, goodHeight);
        view.setLayoutParams(currParams);
    }

    return currParams;
}
```

Finally, next issue is for several views with suitable sizes but in sum they're bigger than allocated size. Maybe I'll just straightly count sizes of views and if the sum with the size of next adding view will be more than allocated size I just disallow to add this view.